# How to export offer file from Bol Retailer API using Python

Tags: python, rest, http, http-headers

I have been trying to export offer file using Python for Bol Retailer API
According to the official docs on [request an offer file export](https://api.bol.com/retailer/public/redoc/v7/retailer.html#operation/post-offer-export)

I have include all the headers and formats but it throws a 400 Bad Request

```
400
Bad Request
b'{\n  "type" : "https://api.bol.com/problems",\n  "title" : "Bad Request",\n  "status" : 400,\n  "detail" : "The supplied content-type media type is not supported.",\n  "host" : "Instance-111",\n  "instance" : "https://api.bol.com/retailer/offers/export"\n}'
```

Here is a minimal example from my code

```
import base64
import requests
import json
import time

class BolService:
    def __init__(self, _id, secret):
        self.host = "https://api.bol.com"
        self.__header = {
            "Accept": "application/vnd.retailer.v7+json",
            "Content-Type": "N/A",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.__get_token(_id, secret)
        }

    def __get_token(self, _id, secret) -> str:
        creds = (_id + ":" + secret).encode('ascii')    #creds : ascii bytes
        creds_b64_b = base64.b64encode(creds)           #creds : base64 bytes
        creds_b64 = creds_b64_b.decode('ascii')         #creds : base64 string
        header = {
            "Authorization":"Basic " + creds_b64
        } 
        link = "https://login.bol.com/token?grant_type=client_credentials"
        response = requests.post(link, headers=header)
        response_data = json.loads(response.content.decode())
        return response_data['access_token']

    def get_offer_file(self):
        path = f"/retailer/offers/export"
        new_header = self.__header.copy()
        new_header["format"] = "CSV"
        response = requests.post(self.host + path, headers=new_header)
        return response
```

**Note**: I have also tried changing the `"Content-Type"` in `self.__header` to `"application/vnd.retailer.v7+json"`, I have also changed the same to add csv using `"application/vnd.retailer.v7+json+csv"` or `"application/vnd.retailer.v7+csv"`. I have also tried adding `self.__header['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'` but nothing seems to work it keeps on throwing the same Bad Request. I have also tried using the v6 of the API instead of v7 but same issue.

I know this is something that should be dealt with the customer service of Bol but they their service is too pathetic to even give a simple reply. Also as of August 2022 [their site](https://api.bol.com/problems) which details API issues is down. Maybe if someone with experience can help here.
I don't think I am missing anything here. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to sucessfully make the POST request.
1st what I did was change the `"Content-Type"` in `self.__header` to `"application/vnd.retailer.v7+json"`

so the header now looks like this

```
self.__header = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.retailer.v7+json",
    "Content-Type": "application/vnd.retailer.v7+json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.__get_token(_id, secret)
}
```

Since we require the content type in JSON format so we have to include a JSON body by dumping our dictionary content using json.dumps

So the get_offer_file method now looks like with `{"format":"CSV"}` as the body

```
def get_offer_file(self):
    path = f"/retailer/offers/export"
    response = requests.post(self.host + path, headers=self.__header, data=json.dumps({"format":"CSV"}))
    return response
```

Here is the full code:

```
import base64
import requests
import json

class BolService:
    def __init__(self, _id, secret):
        self.host = "https://api.bol.com"
        self.__header = {
            "Accept": "application/vnd.retailer.v7+json",
            "Content-Type": "application/vnd.retailer.v7+json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.__get_token(_id, secret)
        }

    def __get_token(self, _id, secret) -> str:
        creds = (_id + ":" + secret).encode('ascii')    #creds : ascii bytes
        creds_b64_b = base64.b64encode(creds)           #creds : base64 bytes
        creds_b64 = creds_b64_b.decode('ascii')         #creds : base64 string
        header = {
            "Authorization":"Basic " + creds_b64
        } 
        link = "https://login.bol.com/token?grant_type=client_credentials"
        response = requests.post(link, headers=header)
        response_data = json.loads(response.content.decode())
        return response_data['access_token']

    def get_offer_file(self):
        path = f"/retailer/offers/export"
        response = requests.post(self.host + path, headers=self.__header, data=json.dumps({"format":"CSV"}))
        return response
```